# Fetching a record between two age ranges and another criteria Php Mysqli javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I have to find a cycling category between different ages and based on gender and the age of the person.

Fields in table = tblcategories = "categories","age_from","age_to","gender"
Records in table = tblcategories = Veteran Male, 40, 49, Male  (are many other records also)

In html form i need to populate with a button, the "categories input textbox" with correct categories value from tblcategories, based on criteria in select query.

On the html form i have an "age" and "gender" input textboxes already populated and in this instance the age = 45 and gender = male but categories is still empty.
Because age = 45 and is between "40" and "49" the categories called "Veteran male" must be populated into categories textbox
I imagine something like this

"SELECT categories FROM tblcategories WHERE $age BETWEEN tblcategories.age_from AND tblcategories.age_to and tblcategories.gender = $gender"

The categories value must then be populated into input textbox using a button.
Any assistance for this beginner will be appreciated

Comment: no idea what the question is

Comment: How do i add the categories value in table to the input textbox on form based on select query

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery Ajax to call PHP scripts and populate the form field [api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)